# How to remove Eclipse 3.8 from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: launcher, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Mars 1 which I would like to use, it could be run and located in `/home/user/Application/eclipse`

When I lock it to the launcher, close eclipse and launch it again, it runs a Eclipse 3.8 which I don't recall.

I believe that Eclipse 3.8 is found under `/home/user/.eclipse`

I go to `/usr/share/applications`, there is a Eclipse (`.desktop`). I open it with `gedit`, it has

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
... ...
Exec=eclipse
Terminal=false
... ...
```

So my question is, I don't need this Eclipse 3.8 and I want to launch Mars 1 from launcher, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to remove an eclipse version installed via apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

You can also see which eclipse is called by the command `eclipse` with:

```
which eclipse
```

in a terminal.

Comment: Are you sure it won't removenot only the oldest eclipse version but also  the latest eclipse version installed?

Comment: When I do this, it returns: `Package 'eclipse' is not installed, so not removed`, but the program is still present in `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/bin`. Any ideas?